# How to get UserID from ASP.NET Identity when sending Rest Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an API which uses ASP.NET Identity, it is fairly easy for me to get the UserId once the `token` has been generated as following

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString())
```

Now I have an external application which is trying to authenticate using this API but I need the UserId of the user who generated the `token`

When I send a request to `http://myapiURL/token` I get the following

1. access_token
2. token_type
3. expires_in
4. userName
5. issued
6. expires

And when I send a request to get `API/Account/UserInfo` using the generated `token` I get the following

1. Email
2. HasRegistered
3. LoginProvider

**Question** How do I get `UserId`?

I have two options,

**A.** I modify `UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()` to have UserId in UserInfoViewModel?

**B.** I create a new method in `ApiController` such as GetUserId (`API/Account/GetUserId`) which runs `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString())` and sends back the 
UserId

Is there any other way?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want UserId in the response of /Token.

By default Identity does not add UserId in response.

so you need to add it manually in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs in method `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
               OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);


            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            ticket.Properties.Dictionary.Add("UserId", user.Id);


            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
```

Comment: This was a great idea, thanks for that, using `ticket.Properties.Dictionary.Add("UserId", user.Id);` simply returns the UserId also - Perfect solution