# Login in a WinForm app using Asp.Net Identity through an API

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-identity

I have a website, using ASP.NET Identity for login. 
Now I need to log in a WinForm application (with a registered user), using Identity from website, sending username and password through an API to Identity.

User data is going to be received by the website through an API made by me, but then I don't know how to use this data to authenticate with Identity. I tried to instantiate LoginModel class from Identity, but it said "it is not intended to be used directly from your code".

I would appreciate if you can give me some suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: see this qiuestion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461571/how-to-get-userid-from-asp-net-identity-when-sending-rest-request and if its has your answer delete your question or it will be marked as a dupliate. thanks or you can more spiceific your problem,

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the same problem, because my API is separated of Identity.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I used SignInManager to log in with credentials taken from API.